# How can I undo the deletion of an email?

Tags: email

Occasionally, I accidentally delete an email from an email account - for IMAP accounts this is usually fine, as it just moves them to the deleted items; I appreciate that any action will have to happen prior to the next sync (when the mail will get deleted from the server), but is there any way to recover/cancel deletion of an email for a POP3 mailbox?

Comment: Depends mail server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends entirely on how you have set up POP3. If you have selected "leave a copy on the server" then yes most likely you can recover it - by going straight to the server. There is also an option to by going in to

> mail>menu>folders>[show more]>deleted items

But that option I think you *may* have to set up. I would **always** recommend you use IMAP for reasons such as this.